# Selenium IDE wildcard in text expression for verifyNotText

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to evaluate the Selenium command `verifyNotText` for `//div[@id='adiv']` for text with a wildcard, such as `Illegal Characters xyz`.

I would like to specify `Illegal.*` or something to match on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there are 3 ways to do it, the first 2 of which will do what I want:

- Globbing: `glob:Illegial*`
- Regular expression: `regex:Illegial.*`
- Exact: `exact:This**`

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp

Comment: Also, I believe this defaults to glob. Here is a link to more information on the different types of pattern matching: http://www.codediesel.com/testing/selenium-ide-pattern-matching/